# How to use regex to make even smaller iteritools sub groups

Tags: python, string, sorting

Right now the paths are only grouped by **year**. I'm trying to group them by the **Frequency** and whether the measuring device was **horizontal** or **vertical**.

**Needed groups (year___Frequency-range___horizontal/vertical)**
*in that order*

```
2020___20-80M___ver  
2020___80M-200MHz___hor   
2020___80M-200MHz___ver  
2020___200M-1000MHz___hor   
2020___200M-1000MHz___ver  
2020___1000M-6000MHz___hor   
2020___1000M-6000MHz___ver  
2020___6000M-8000MHz___hor   
2020___6000M-8000MHz___ver

**next round**

2021___20-80M___ver  
2022___80M-200MHz___hor
```

```py
paths_by_year = {'2020': ['C:\\Users\\M0182965\\Desktop\\emc2\\Primerjave_referencnih_kalibracij\\2020_06_19\\1000M-6000MHz_BBHA9120J_mobile-rack_200Vm_hor', 'C:\\Users\\M0182965\\Desktop\\emc2\\Primerjave_referencnih_kalibracij\\2020_06_19\\1000M-6000MHz_BBHA9120J_mobile-rack_200Vm_ver', 'C:\\Users\\M0182965\\Desktop\\emc2\\Primerjave_referencnih_kalibracij\\2020_06_19\\20-80M_70Vm_vertical_VHBD9134', 'C:\\Users\\M0182965\\Desktop\\emc2\\Primerjave_referencnih_kalibracij\\2020_06_19\\200M-1000MHz_STLP9128_FLH1000B_200Vm_hor', 'C:\\Users\\M0182965\\Desktop\\emc2\\Primerjave_referencnih_kalibracij\\2020_06_19\\200M-1000MHz_STLP9128_FLH1000B_200Vm_ver', 'C:\\Users\\M0182965\\Desktop\\emc2\\Primerjave_referencnih_kalibracij\\2020_06_19\\6000M-8000MHz_BBHA9120J_mobile-rack_200Vm_hor', 'C:\\Users\\M0182965\\Desktop\\emc2\\Primerjave_referencnih_kalibracij\\2020_06_19\\6000M-8000MHz_BBHA9120J_mobile-rack_200Vm_ver', 'C:\\Users\\M0182965\\Desktop\\emc2\\Primerjave_referencnih_kalibracij\\2020_06_19\\80M-200MHz_STLP9128_extender_PRANA_150Vm_hor', 'C:\\Users\\M0182965\\Desktop\\emc2\\Primerjave_referencnih_kalibracij\\2020_06_19\\80M-200MHz_STLP9128_extender_PRANA_150Vm_ver'], '2021': ['C:\\Users\\M0182965\\Desktop\\emc2\\Primerjave_referencnih_kalibracij\\2021_07_01\\ref-cal_200M-1000MHz_STLP9128_FLH1000B_200Vm_hor', 'C:\\Users\\M0182965\\Desktop\\emc2\\Primerjave_referencnih_kalibracij\\2021_07_01\\ref-cal_200M-1000MHz_STLP9128_FLH1000B_200Vm_ver', 'C:\\Users\\M0182965\\Desktop\\emc2\\Primerjave_referencnih_kalibracij\\2021_07_01\\Ref_Cal_1000M-6000M_200Vm_hor_BBHA9120J', 'C:\\Users\\M0182965\\Desktop\\emc2\\Primerjave_referencnih_kalibracij\\2021_07_01\\Ref_Cal_1000M-6000M_200Vm_ver_BBHA9120J', 'C:\\Users\\M0182965\\Desktop\\emc2\\Primerjave_referencnih_kalibracij\\2021_07_01\\ref_cal_20-80M_70Vm_vertical_VHBD9134', 'C:\\Users\\M0182965\\Desktop\\emc2\\Primerjave_referencnih_kalibracij\\2021_07_01\\ref_cal_6000M-8000MHz_BBHA9120J_mobile-rack_200Vm_hor', 'C:\\Users\\M0182965\\Desktop\\emc2\\Primerjave_referencnih_kalibracij\\2021_07_01\\ref_cal_6000M-8000MHz_BBHA9120J_mobile-rack_200Vm_ver', 'C:\\Users\\M0182965\\Desktop\\emc2\\Primerjave_referencnih_kalibracij\\2021_07_01\\ref_cal_80M-200MHz_STLP9128_extender_PRANA_150Vm_hor', 'C:\\Users\\M0182965\\Desktop\\emc2\\Primerjave_referencnih_kalibracij\\2021_07_01\\ref_cal_80M-200MHz_STLP9128_extender_PRANA_150Vm_ver'], '2022': ['C:\\Users\\M0182965\\Desktop\\emc2\\Primerjave_referencnih_kalibracij\\2022_05_12\\ref-cal_200M-1000MHz_STLP9128_FLH1000B_200Vm_hor_new_Mount', 'C:\\Users\\M0182965\\Desktop\\emc2\\Primerjave_referencnih_kalibracij\\2022_05_12\\ref-cal_200M-1000MHz_STLP9128_FLH1000B_200Vm_ver', 'C:\\Users\\M0182965\\Desktop\\emc2\\Primerjave_referencnih_kalibracij\\2022_05_12\\ref-cal_80M-200MHz_STLP9128_FLH1000B_200Vm_hor_new_Mount', 'C:\\Users\\M0182965\\Desktop\\emc2\\Primerjave_referencnih_kalibracij\\2022_05_12\\ref-cal_80M-200MHz_STLP9128_FLH1000B_200Vm_ver_new_Mount', 'C:\\Users\\M0182965\\Desktop\\emc2\\Primerjave_referencnih_kalibracij\\2022_05_12\\Ref_Cal_1000M-6000M_200Vm_Hor_BBHA9120J_new_Mount', 'C:\\Users\\M0182965\\Desktop\\emc2\\Primerjave_referencnih_kalibracij\\2022_05_12\\Ref_Cal_1000M-6000M_200Vm_Ver_BBHA9120J_new_Mount', 'C:\\Users\\M0182965\\Desktop\\emc2\\Primerjave_referencnih_kalibracij\\2022_05_12\\ref_cal_20-80M_70Vm_vertical_VHBD9134_new_Mount', 'C:\\Users\\M0182965\\Desktop\\emc2\\Primerjave_referencnih_kalibracij\\2022_05_12\\Ref_Cal_6000M-8000MHz_HA9251-48_200Vm_hor_new_Mount', 'C:\\Users\\M0182965\\Desktop\\emc2\\Primerjave_referencnih_kalibracij\\2022_05_12\\Ref_Cal_6000M-8000MHz_HA9251-48_200Vm_ver_new_Mount']}
    
def extract_frequency(path: string):
    frequency = re.search(r"20-80M", path)
    return frequency.group(0)[1:15]

for key, group in itertools.groupby(tabela_path, extract_frequency):
    paths_by_year[key] = list(group)

print(tabela_path)
```

Comment: what is your expected output?

Comment: `itertools.groupby` can only group elements that are already adjacent. For your purpose, use a dict of lists instead. Or a dict of dicts if you want to have subgroups inside the groups.

Comment: There is also `more_itertools.map_reduce` which can build the dict of lists for you: https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#more_itertools.map_reduce

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First extract the information you want:

```
result = []
for key, value in paths_by_year.items():
    for val in value:
        *_, name = val.split('\\')
        m = re.search(r"(?:ref[-_]cal)?(\d+M?-\d+MH?z?).*(hor|ver)", name, re.I)
        if m:
            freq_range, direction = m.groups()
        result.append((key, freq_range, direction))
```

Now you have a list with tuples of 3 values (`key, freq_range, direction`)
Then you can sort them by defining a key, it sorts first by year, then searches for the first number in the 2nd value, converts it as int and sorts that, and finally the direction.

```
out = sorted(result, key=lambda x: (x[0], int(x[1].split('-')[0].strip('M')), x[2]))
```

Output:

```
[('2020', '20-80M', 'ver'),
 ('2020', '80M-200MHz', 'hor'),
 ('2020', '80M-200MHz', 'ver'),
 ('2020', '200M-1000MHz', 'hor'),
 ('2020', '200M-1000MHz', 'ver'),
 ('2020', '1000M-6000MHz', 'hor'),
 ('2020', '1000M-6000MHz', 'ver'),
 ('2020', '6000M-8000MHz', 'hor'),
 ('2020', '6000M-8000MHz', 'ver'),
 ('2021', '20-80M', 'ver'),
 ('2021', '80M-200MHz', 'hor'),
 ('2021', '80M-200MHz', 'ver'),
 ('2021', '200M-1000MHz', 'hor'),
 ('2021', '200M-1000MHz', 'ver'),
 ('2021', '1000M-6000M', 'hor'),
 ('2021', '1000M-6000M', 'ver'),
 ('2021', '6000M-8000MHz', 'hor'),
 ('2021', '6000M-8000MHz', 'ver'),
 ('2022', '20-80M', 'ver'),
 ('2022', '80M-200MHz', 'hor'),
 ('2022', '80M-200MHz', 'ver'),
 ('2022', '200M-1000MHz', 'hor'),
 ('2022', '200M-1000MHz', 'ver'),
 ('2022', '1000M-6000M', 'Hor'),
 ('2022', '1000M-6000M', 'Ver'),
 ('2022', '6000M-8000MHz', 'hor'),
 ('2022', '6000M-8000MHz', 'ver')]
```

If you want to join them to one string with `__` as delimiter just run this line:

```
list(map('__'.join, out))
```

Comment: thank you for your excelent regex skills, among others. Im sorry for the question not being precise enough, I promise I will be better next time

Comment: https://www.lawtechnologytoday.org/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/thankyou.jpg

Answer (score 0):

I think you should have explained it better. From what I understood, it is something like this (you can change "numbers" as you want):

```
from collections import defaultdict
import numpy as np

d = defaultdict(dict)

paths = [
    "2020___20-80M___ver",
    "2020___80M-200MHz___hor",
    "2020___80M-200MHz___ver",
    "2020___200M-1000MHz___hor",
    "2020___200M-1000MHz___ver",
    "2020___1000M-6000MHz___hor",
    "2020___1000M-6000MHz___ver",
    "2020___6000M-8000MHz___hor",
    "2020___6000M-8000MHz___ver"]

numbers = np.random.randint(0, 10, size=len(paths)).tolist()

for path, number in zip(paths, numbers):
    groups = path.split('___')
    year, frequency, orientation = groups
    freq = {}
    freq[orientation] = number

    d[year][frequency] = freq

print(dict(d))
```

Comment: You can write `defaultdict(dict)` rather than `defaultdict(lambda: dict())`

Comment: Also `year, frequency, orientation = path.split('___')`

Comment: Correct, Stef. Thank you.